# Downloading a file: works with IE but not with Firefox

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

the following servlet works if we want to download a file through Internet Explorer 11  (and Edge) :

```
    private void writeFileToClient(byte[] imageData, String imageMimeType, HttpServletRequest request,
       HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
   {
       if (imageData != null && imageData.length > 0)
       {
           if (imageMimeType != null)
           {
               response.setHeader("Content-Type", imageMimeType);
           }
           response.setContentLength(imageData.length);
           ServletOutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
           ouputStream.write(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
           ouputStream.flush();
           ouputStream.close();
       }
   }
```

imageMimeType equals application/octet-stream

However it does not work with Firefox Quantum.

Any idea what could be missing ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It is worth ... If we remove the content type, it does not work on Firefox and IE ...

Comment: If the response is a file to be saved, set a Content-Disposition header:   `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",  "attachment; filename=\"filename\"");`